# How to measure the time of individual function calls in a large R project?

Tags: r, profiling, benchmarking, profvis

I have a somewhat large R project and would like to identify performance bottlenecks by measuring how long the individual functions take to execute. I know of tools like `microbenchmark` for checking individual lines of code.

Is it possible to have a tool track the execution times of the individually called functions and then report the results at the end?

In practice, the idea would be that I have a `script.R`

```
plot(cars)
plot(cars + 1)
```

and after running the "benchmark tool" over it, get a result that looks something like this:

```
plot(cars): 0.1s
plot(cars + 1): 0.1s
```

How would I go about achieving something like this?

Comment: There's a whole chapter on profiling in Advanced R. Check it out: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-measure.html

Comment: What you're asking about is called *profiling*. There is at least one package for it in R, `profvis`. The link MrFlick provided is likely one of the better you'll find.

Comment: I think Hadley's book doesn't mention the base function for reporting timing, `summaryRprof()`.  For the first pass to look at a big project I prefer it to `profvis` because it quickly shows me which functions (or which lines, if you enable that) are the heavy users.  I find that harder to work out with the `profvis` displays, though they are great for looking at the details.